# Bootstrap images not displayed in a single row

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I've been trying to create few images that should be displayed in a single row.
Currently it is displayed one-by-one.

[image: Example]

Here's my code:

```
# CSS:
.emblems-section {
    z-index: 1;
    text-align: center;
}

<header>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 emblems-section justify-content-center align-items-center">
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-xs-4">
                    <img src="img/leagueEmblem.png" class="img-fluid" alt="Statistics for League of Legends">
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-xs-4">
                    <img src="img/overwatchEmblem.png" class="img-fluid" alt="Statistics for Overwatch">
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-xs-4">
                    <img src="img/dotaEmblem.png" class="img-fluid" alt="Statistics for Dota2">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone looking for the same solution, the answer is d-flex within the parent div.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 emblems-section justify-content-center align-items-center">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-xs-4">
                    <img src="img/leagueEmblem.png" class="img-fluid" alt="Statistics for League of Legends">
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-xs-4">
                    <img src="img/overwatchEmblem.png" class="img-fluid" alt="Statistics for Overwatch">
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-xs-4">
                    <img src="img/dotaEmblem.png" class="img-fluid" alt="Statistics for Dota2">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

//you have to add row after col-md-12

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

It is best practice that  try to avoid unnecessary **div** or other elements in code structure. so you don't need to use **col-md-12** just replace **col-md-12** to **row** class and remove duplicate **row** div.

Use below code, by using this you can remove one unrequired **div** element, so your code looks compressed and beautiful.

```
<header>
    <div class="container">            
          <div class="row emblems-section justify-content-center align-items-center">
              <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-xs-4">
                  <img src="img/leagueEmblem.png" class="img-fluid" alt="Statistics for League of Legends">
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-xs-4">
                  <img src="img/overwatchEmblem.png" class="img-fluid" alt="Statistics for Overwatch">
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-xs-4">
                  <img src="img/dotaEmblem.png" class="img-fluid" alt="Statistics for Dota2">
              </div>
          </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 d-flex emblems-section justify-content-center align-items-center">
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-xs-4">
                <img src="img/leagueEmblem.png" class="img-fluid" alt="Statistics for League of Legends">
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-xs-4">
                <img src="img/overwatchEmblem.png" class="img-fluid" alt="Statistics for Overwatch">
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-xs-4">
                <img src="img/dotaEmblem.png" class="img-fluid" alt="Statistics for Dota2">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

you can add d-flex class with col-md-12